# Express Routes not functioning

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I am trying to create a route to my users file as well as others but when I use postman to send a get request to https://localhost:3000/api/users I get a "Cannot GET api/users/ error.

I have tried putting the require statement into a variable and then passing it to the app.use() function. I also made sure the in my users.js file that the first parameter is only a "/". Also it is not just the users route it is all of my routes that do not work. Can someone see my mistake?

Here is the server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

const app = express();

//Connect DB

connectDB();

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("API Running"));

//define routes

const userRoute = require("./routes/api/users");

app.use("api/users", userRoute);
app.use("api/auth", require("./routes/api/auth"));
app.use("api/profile", 
require("./routes/api/profile"));
app.use("api/posts", require("./routes/api/posts"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server started on port: ${PORT}
`)
);
```

And here is the users.js file, all of the other router files are similar just with different names.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// @route    get api/users
// @desc     test route
// @ access  Public

router.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("User Route"));

module.exports = router;
```

I also tried changing the last line in users.js to export default router but that just resulted in an unexpected token error. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `'/'` before your route definitions in the server.js file. So your route definition for the users will be `app.use("/api/users", userRoute)`. Do the same for all your route definitions

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your line `app.use("api/users", userRoute);` to `app.use("/api/users", userRoute);` in server.js

Comment: Awesome that solved my issue thanks for the help!